# What jar to download for running with an application in place of javaee api

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, fitnesse

I am trying to run a Fitnesse project on a server. The java code has an import

```
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
```

What jar can I use instead of javaee api 5 that will not create the

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException
```

error message?

Answer (score 2):

Its javax.faces, so you need an implementation for Javaserver Faces.

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/

The JEE platform consists of a great number of APIs and specifications each with their own set of implementations. If you don't want to use a JEE container such as Glassfish, JBoss or Weblogic which provides all the implementations you need out of the box, then you'll have to figure out which APIs / specifications you want to be using in your application and find a proper implementation for them, and deploy it along with your application.

In the case of JSF, Mojarra (which can be downloaded from the above link) is the "reference implementation".

A small research note: generally it is enough to just copy/paste the package name into Google to find out what API it belongs too. Ex 'java javax.faces'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the published java-ee 5 API, which can only be used at compile time and not runtime.

You can find a suitable alternative at [The Central Repository Search Engine](http://search.maven.org) by using `fc: javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException` as a search term.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using javaee api from java.net in your maven dependency.
Instead just download and install the J2EE SDK, and the javaee.jar can be found in the `\J2EE_SDK_FOLDER\lib` folder. Include it into your local Maven repository or poject classpath

`-->`  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html